# 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_int32'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement CTC loss to audio files but I get the following error:

> TensorFlow has no attribute 'to_int32'

I'm running tf.**version** 2.0.0.

I think it's with the version, I'm currently using, as we see the error is thrown in the package itself  ' tensorflow_backend.py' code.

I have imported packages as "tensorflow.keras.class_name" with backend as K. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast the tensor in TensorFlow 2 as follows:

```
tf.cast(my_tensor, tf.int32)
```

You can read the documentation of the method in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast

You can also see that the `to_int32` is deprecated and was used in TensorFlow 1
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/to_int32

Answer (score 0):

After you make the import just write

```
tf.to_int=lambda x: tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
```

This is similar to writing the behavior of `tf.to_int` in everywhere in the code, so you don't have to manually edit a TF1.0 code